# Android onActivityResult() returning NullPointerException on image capture

Tags: java, android, image, nullpointerexception

I'm having trouble with receiving the data capture from a Camera intent I have developed. I have used the code present in the android API guides. Can anyone tell where I am going wrong? I can see that the `who=null` and `data=null` parameters present in the LogCat printout are probably causing the error but I'm unsure as to why that is.

**Camera Activity**

```
//ESSENTIAL VARIABLES - DD - 29/04/2013
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private Uri fileUri;
MenuItem item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_snap_camera);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Gets the OutputMediaFileUri and accepts media type as a parameter
 * @param type
 * @return
 */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * Method taking media type as a parameter and will save images taken to a public directory on users' device.
 * @param type
 * @return
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CrowdSnapCymru");

    if(!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if(! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("CrowdSnapCymru", "failed to create photo directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;

}

/**
 * Receives the result of Camera intent. 
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to: \n" + data.getData() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "User canceled the image capture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image capture failed. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The code loads the Camera application and will produce the successful result if I cancel the application but if I accept the image or `RESULT_OKAY` the `NullPointerException` is produced.

**LogCat Printout**

```
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru/rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru.SnapCamera}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru.SnapCamera.onActivityResult(SnapCamera.java:84)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
05-01 09:57:48.894: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
```

Any advice would be brilliant. Pretty new to using Camera application in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing Following File URI as `EXTRA_OUTPUT` as follow. Your `onCreate` would look like :

```
Uri picUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_snap_camera);
    String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/picture.jpg";  
    File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath); 
    picUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri        
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,  picUri );
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Then `onActivityResult` use `picUri` to access image. Declare `picUri` as a instance variable in your activity. So it will be available in `onActivityResult`

Comment: could you provide an example? I see your logic but the implementation is confusing.

Comment: Example of what ?? I mean what you want to achieve ??

Comment: how to access the `picUri` image in `onActivityResult`. Sorry really new to this.

Comment: Ohh...got the point...see edited answer above....Declare `picUri` as instance variable in your activity.

Comment: thank you :) and I suppose I can then call `data.getExtras()` to acquire the variable in `onActivityResult()`

Answer (score 3):

Save your fileUri variable somewhere and use it in onActivityResult instead of data.getData